# Dnu restore : Unable to locate EntityFramework.Commands >= 7.0.0-beta7

Tags: asp.net-core, dnu

I am trying my hands on asp.net 5 . I created a asp.net5 mvc application from the template that comes with visual studio 2015.
But the dnu restore is not working on the src folder.

Nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

Here is what i did

```
C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication\src\WebApplication> dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                   Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                   -----
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       clr     x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       coreclr x64          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta7       clr     x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes default
       1.0.0-beta8-15530 clr     x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta8-15548 clr     x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta8-15548 coreclr x86          C:\Users\sam\.dnx\runtimes


C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication\src\WebApplication> dnu restore
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta7-15532

Restoring packages for C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication\src\WebApplication\project.json
Unable to locate EntityFramework.Commands >= 7.0.0-beta7
Unable to locate Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets >= 1.0.0-beta7
Unable to locate Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader >= 14.0.0-beta7
Writing lock file C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication\src\WebApplication\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 1698ms elapsed

Errors in C:\Users\sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication\src\WebApplication\project.json
    Unable to locate EntityFramework.Commands >= 7.0.0-beta7
    Unable to locate Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets >= 1.0.0-beta7
    Unable to locate Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader >= 14.0.0-beta7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding package sources. Here are mine, which work just fine (even on Azure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="Roslyn" value="https://www.myget.org/F/roslyn-nightly/" />
    <add key="DotNet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefx/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You really saved my day!

Comment: Nuget.config in your project root